# change of variables of a ODE, proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a very simple question )= , but I never understood how to make changes of variables in a differential equation and why!
I want to see also a proof but let´s start with an example, let the ODE: 
$
y^{\left( 2 \right)}  + \frac{1}
{{x^4 }}y = 0
$

where $
y^{\left( 2 \right)}  = \frac{d}
{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{dx}}} \right)
$

clearly I assuming that y it´s a function that depends on x.
Let´s do the change of variable 1/x = s , what will be the new equation? and how can i compute it?

Comment: Changing variables in an ODE is done with the chain rule.  For the example you gave, we have $s=1/x$, so set $v(s):=y(x)$, so that $y(x) = v(1/x)$. Then by the chain rule, you compute $y(x)$, $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ in terms of $s$ and $v(s),v'(s),v''(s)$ and substitute them into your original ODE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original PDE is:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -\frac{y}{x^4}$$

If we let $s= x^{-1}$ then we have:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{dx})$$

But,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{ds} \frac{ds}{dx} = \frac{dy}{ds} [-x^{-2}]$$

Thus, we have:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{ds} [-x^{-2}])$$

The above simplifies to:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -x^{-2} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{ds}) +  \frac{dy}{ds} [2x^{-3}])$$

The first term above simplifies to:

$$-x^{-2} \frac{d^2y}{ds^2} (\frac{ds}{dx})$$

which in turn simplifies to:

$$x^{-4} \frac{d^2y}{ds^2}$$

Putting together everything we have:

$$x^{-4} \frac{d^2y}{ds^2} +  \frac{dy}{ds} [2x^{-3}]) = -s^4 y$$

Comment: Except that you should write everything in terms of $s$ so $s^4 d^2y/ds^2 + 2s^3dy/ds + s^4y=0$.

Comment: @jeff true, I did notice that. But, then I did not edit it as if the OP understand the logic he/she should be able to fix the typos (if any) and fill the gaps. To @ august Please feel free to edit my answer to fix any typos/fill the gaps.

Comment: Sorry Dx I don´t understand this step $$
\frac{d}
{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{ds}}} \right) = \frac{{d^2 y}}
{{ds^2 }}\left( {\frac{{ds}}
{{dx}}} \right)
$$
Dx

Comment: @August It follows from chain rule. $$\frac{d}
{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{ds}}} \right) = \frac{d}
{{ds}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{ds}}} \right) \   \left( {\frac{{ds}}
{{dx}}} \right)$$

Comment: @tards Thanks! I Have the last question related with this. Suppose we have an ODE $$
\frac{{d^2 y}}
{{dx^2 }} = f\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{dx}},y,x} \right)
$$
If I try with the change of variable $$
g\left( y \right) = u
$$
If I want to compute $$
\frac{{d^2 y}}
{{dx^2 }} = \frac{d}
{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}
{{dx}}} \right)
$$
I must start with $$
{\frac{{dy}}
{{dx}}}
$$
 but using $ g(y) = u $ we have $$
\frac{{du}}
{{dx}} = \frac{{dg}}
{{dy}} \cdot \frac{{dy}}
{{dx}}
$$
and then $$
\frac{{du}}
{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dg}}
{{dy}}} \right)^{ - 1}  = \frac{{dy}}
{{dx}}
$$
and now what ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually say $y=h(u)$ *i.e.* $h$ is the inverse of $g$.
Then 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dh}{dx}= \frac{dh}{du} \frac{du}{dx},$$ *i.e.* $y$ is absent.

Then
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
=
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \frac{dh}{du} + \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dh}{du} \right)$$
but 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dh}{du} \right)
=\frac{d}{du} \left( \frac{dh}{du} \right) 
* \frac{du}{dx}
=
\frac{d^2h}{du^2} \frac{du}{dx},$$
and again $y$ is absent.

And so on.

Simply replace $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ with these functions of $u$ and $x$; *e.g.* $y=u^2$:

- $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} = 2u \frac{du}{dx}$.
- $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^u}{dx^2} \cdot 2y + \frac{du}{dx} \frac{du}{dx} \cdot 2 = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \cdot 2y+2 \left( \frac{du}{dx} \right)^2$.

Comment: I've attempted to edit your answer to include [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020). You should check it over to ensure that I didn't inadvertently introduce any errors.

Comment: sorry last line u instead of y